# Jquery not working on the following code:

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the code in the script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mainobject').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

And this is the code in the index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

        <title>Hitler Map</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"></link>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1 id="title">
        Content
        </h1>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">

    </div>

    <div id="mainobject">content1
        <div id="aides">subcontent
        <ul id="list1">
            <li class="items">nananana batman</li>
            <li class="items">woohoo</li>
        </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="family">Family
        <ul id="list2">
            <li class="items">spoder-man</li>
            <li class="items">dolan</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        </div>



</body>
</html>
```

The stylesheet works fine, but the Javascript is working neither locally nor on a server. Please help? It is a simple enough code.

Comment: Is that `div` actually not closed or was that a copy/paste issue?  Also, in the code above, you have not included jquery.

Comment: Can we assume that this is not your full HTML and only a part of it?

Comment: Are you noticing any errors in your console?

Comment: Put script.js below the jquery, because it depend on jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not including Jquery

Add the following line inside head tag:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

Also close ul tag

```
<ul>
<li id="mainobject">some content</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the jquery issue! Included it, but issue remains. I have updated the answer with the full code from index, please check :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you added Jquery plugin  to your document.

And

Wrong html

```
<ul>
    <div id="mainobject">some content
    <ul>
```

should be

```
    <ul>
    <li  id="mainobject">some content </li>  //seems here li.Div not allowed
    </ul>
```

Comment: `<div>` is not a valid child element of `<ul>`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the ul issue. It still isn't working though :(

Comment: @user2370459 Glad to help you. Also you forgot to close the ul tag.And there are online tools to validate your html.Please get use of them.Good luck with the project. :)
http://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html

Answer (score 0):

jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mainobject').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

HTML
 - Changed `<div>` to `li`, since div isn't allowed inside an `<ul></ul>` unordered list.
Always make sure you close all elements that need to be closed in HTML. In your sourcecode you forgot to close the `<div>` on which you wanted to use jQuery.

```
<head>

        <title>some content</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"></link>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1 id="title">
        Some more content
        </h1>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">

    </div>

<ul>
    <li id="mainobject">some content</li>
<ul>
```

In case that your script.js is not the jQuery lib, add into the `<head>` tag

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: No matter it is solved! I wasn't adding the jQuery lib before the script tag for the js file. Hence it wasn't recognizing the js file's syntax.
THANKS A LOT GUYS :D

Answer (score 0):

you must include your external script AFTER jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Put script.js below the jquery, because it depend on jquery

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

**Note:** use minified version of jquery spped up the webpage

use `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>` instead of `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`

Also use Jquery migrate plugin for deprecated function works

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.js"></script>
```